# Where can I find ContactsListActivity?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm firing off an intent that opens up a list of my contacts, but so far I'm unable to find the resulting activity (`ContactsListActivity`) anywhere in the android source code. I've tried grepping the platform 10 source code, and searching on https://android.googlesource.com. Anyone know where I can find this?

The intent looks like the following:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

And logcat gives the following output:

```
I/ActivityManager(   52): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts cmp=com.android.contacts/.ContactsListActivity }
I/ContactsListActivity(  104): Called with action: android.intent.action.PICK
I/ActivityManager(   52): Displayed activity com.android.contacts/.ContactsListActivity: 518 ms (total 518 ms)
```

The contacts app in the source code does not seem to contain this activity either:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/froyo-release/src/com/android/contacts/ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in package `com.android.contacts`:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/froyo-release/src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java

Comment: Oh my.. I looked in that folder but managed to miss it. Thanks!